# @XmlRootElement missing in generated classes

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, wsdl

I have a `wsdl` file that I get from the client, in my application I generate the `java` classes from the `wsdl` file using the plugin `jaxb2-maven-plugin`, then I build my object and send it to the client

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sri-autorizacion-comprobantes</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/wsdl</outputDirectory>
                            <packageName>autorizacion</packageName>
                            <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/PayerWebService.wsdl</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The problem when I send the generated object I get this error:

```
> unable to marshal type "autorizacion.ConfirmPayer10" as an element
> because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
```